# How listen for check box in JFace Table Viewer

Tags: java, eclipse, jface, viewer

I am using a Table Viewer with check boxes as following:

```
final TableViewer legendViewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.CHECK);
```

What is THE solution to listen to check boxes selection/unselection in this viewer ?

Thanks in advance,
Manu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You listen for `SWT.Selection` events on the `Table` and check for `event.detail == SWT.CHECK`...

See this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTTableSimpleDemo.htm) for actual code....

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at class `CheckboxTableViewer` derived from `TableViewer` which simplifies the use of a TableViewer with the `SWT.CHECK` style.

Add an implementaion of `ICheckStateListener` to your `CheckboxTableViewer` via `addCheckStateListener()`. The only method you have to implement is `checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event)` where `event` contains all necessary information about the state change.

If you need only one column you can create a CheckboxTableViewer like this:

```
CheckboxTableViewer myTableViewer = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(parent, style);
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding @Tonny's answer, here's the listener you would use:

```
tableViewer.getTable().addListener(SWT.Selection, (e) -> {      
    if (e.detail == SWT.CHECK) {
        MyModel modelObj = (MyModel) e.item.getData();
        TableItem item = (TableItem) e.item;
        System.out.println("ITEM CHECKED -> " + item.getChecked());
    }
});
```

You see, you can cast the widget to `TableItem` to understand whether the user has either checked or unchecked the checkbox.

---

Still, as @Claimos' says, I would just use a JFace `CheckboxTableViewer`.